# Error in x[["endpoint"]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in rtweet CRAN package

Tags: r, twitter

I am using a package `rtweet` to download tweets based on a keyword.
The function `search_tweets()` returned an error after successfully working for more than 2 months.

Now it's showing the error:

```
# load twitter library - the rtweet library is recommended now over twitteR
 library(rtweet)
 # plotting and pipes - tidyverse!
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)
 # text mining library
 library(tidytext)
 # plotting packages
 library(igraph)
 library(ggraph)

 cat ("Initializing.... \n")
Initializing.... 
 cat("Enter a keyword whose analysis you want to check: ");
Enter a keyword whose analysis you want to check: > #a <- readLines("stdin",n=1)   #doesnot work in Rstudio

 a = "@realdonaldtrump"
 src_tweets <- search_tweets(q = a, n = 1000,
+                             lang = "en",
+                             include_rts = TRUE)
Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  : 
  Unauthorized (HTTP 401).
```

Comment: I had the same problem but setting `http://127.0.0.1:1410` as the callback URL fixed it. See [here](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/issues/157).

Comment: i have used no twitter app here , simply followed the steps from here : https://earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/get-data-using-apis/text-mining-twitter-data-intro-r/